# Why is my Content Security Policy blocking form data being sent?

Tags: c#, .net, content-security-policy

I have a csp similar to:

```
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; form-action 'self' *.example.com;
```

but for some reason I get an error saying

> Refused to send form data to http://www.test.example.com/ because it
>   violates the following content security policy form-action 'self'
>   *.example.com"

It appears to work on my local machine but when migrated to my server the issue arises. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing the difference?

Comment: How are you setting the policy? Using a `meta` element? Have you checked the response headers from the server to see if it’s already adding a Content-Security-Policy response header?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's likely that the cause is in the details that you've chosen to make anonymous.